# map <C-\>^] の意味

Tags: vim

https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Vim-editor
の
3.5.3 Usage
に

```
map <C-\>^] :GtagsCursor<CR>
```

と記述があります。

`<C-\>^]` の部分の解説をお願いいたします。

コントロールキーを押しながらバックスラッシュを押下するのだろうとは思ったのですが、その先がわかりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5):

`<C-\>` の部分は、ご推察の通りコントロールキーを押しながらバックスラッシュを押下であっています。

`^]` はコントロールキーを押しながら `]` を押すと入力できます。このコントロール文字をスクリプトに直接書くには、Vim では挿入モードで `<C-v><C-]>` の順にキーを押せば入力できます。
実際に設定したい場合は、以下のように `<>` 記法で設定した方がわかりやすいでしょう。

```
nnoremap <C-\><C-]> :GtagsCursor<CR>
```

** 回答当初、`<C-[>` と見間違えてエスケープキーだと回答していましたが、間違っていたので修正しました。